# Defining and using a Python class within a ROS catkin workspace

Tags: python, ros

I am running ROS Indigo. I have what should be a simple problem: I have a utility class in my package that I want to be callable from our scripts. It only needs to be called within our own package; I don't need it to be available to other ROS packages.

I defined a class named HandControl in a file HandControl.py. All my attempts to import it, or use it without importing, fail. Where in the catkin workspace do I put it -- the root of the package, or in scripts? Do I need `__init.py__` anywhere (I have tried several places)?

Comment: _(1)_ Please show your project structure _(2)_ Show the full traceback your getting when your imports fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a good practice to follow the standards of Python and ROS here. Scripts are typically placed in `/script` directory and they should *not* be imported into other python scripts. Reusable python code is an indication of a python module. Python modules should be placed in `/src/package_name` and there you should create `__init__.py` as well. This module will be available everywhere in your catkin workspace. There is a good chance this structure will help you in the future to structure things, even though you may not seem to need it at the moment. Project typically grow and following guidelines helps to maintain good code. For more specific details checkout this [python doc](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/installing_python.html).

Answer (score -2):

Erica,

please see [this](https://github.com/asafch/komodo) school project, which was written in Python and run on ROS Indigo. If you'd look in the `/scripts` folder, you can see an example of a custom class that is being called from other scripts. If you'd look into the launch files in `/launch` you can see an example of configuring the ROS nodes - maybe that is your problem.

Comment: which is the custom class? I see quite a few here, which look like standard ROS nodes. My class is not a node.

Comment: OK, so it turns out that my problem lay elsewhere; I redid the catkin workspace process and now things are working as far as the import goes. That said your project was a valuable sanity check so I have given an upvote and thank you.